# Need to change a lot of values in a single column based on the content of the column

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a column that contains entirely URLs referring to podcast audio files. Almost all of them have the format `http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS-to-YYYMMDD-HHMMSS.mp3`.

The problem is that we now have so many files in the /audio/ folder that it takes a long time to load that folder in windows explorer. So we wanted to move all of them into folders by year -> eg `http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/20060321-140000-to-20000321-150000.mp3` gets moved to `http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2006/20060321-140000-to-20000321-150000.mp3` and we have to update all of our urls in the database to reflect the new folder structure. We have files from 2006 to 2015 with this naming convention, and around September of 2015 we switched so that all new podcasts automatically used the year folder structure and don't need to be updated.

I'm rather inexperienced with SQL - it's part of my job but was a "nice to have" when hired. Anyways my attempt is this:

```
/*urls are in structure of = 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/audio/YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS-to-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.mp3 but then some aren't in this format which we ignore. All urls are in the column of the table named "url"*/
UPDATE table.podcast_episodes
SET url = CASE 
    WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2006____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN url = concat(substring(url,1,41),'2006/',substring(url FROM 42))
    WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2007____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN url = concat(substring(url,1,41),'2007/',substring(url FROM 42))
    WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2008____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN url = concat(substring(url,1,41),'2008/',substring(url FROM 42))
    WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2009____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN url = concat(substring(url,1,41),'2009/',substring(url FROM 42))
    WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2010____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN url = concat(substring(url,1,41),'2010/',substring(url FROM 42))
    WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2011____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN url = concat(substring(url,1,41),'2010/',substring(url FROM 42))
    WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2012____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN url = concat(substring(url,1,41),'2011/',substring(url FROM 42))
    WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2013____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN url = concat(substring(url,1,41),'2012/',substring(url FROM 42))
    WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2014____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN url = concat(substring(url,1,41),'2014/',substring(url FROM 42))
    WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2015____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN url = concat(substring(url,1,41),'2015/',substring(url FROM 42))
    /* do nothing */
    ELSE url= url
END
```

The problem with it is it just sets the URL field to 0 when it matches the case statements, or 1 when it hits the "else" statement, which isn't what I want.

Comment: OK, so what's it doing and what's wrong with it? Please ask a question.

Comment: I edited my original post. I included:

"The problem with it is it just sets the URL field to 0 when it matches the case statements, or 1 when it hits the "else" statement, which isn't what I want."

Comment: Surely "it's NOT part of my job but..." ??

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not using your ELSE or CASE statements properly.  The format is

```
CASE WHEN url LIKE ... THEN (the concatenated value that you're setting url to).
```

You don't do

```
THEN url = (concatenated value you're creating)
```

because it'll fail the way you're seeing it fail.  If you made a slight modification like this:

```
UPDATE podcast_episodes
SET url = CASE 
WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2006____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN concat(substring(url,1,41),'2006/',substring(url FROM 42))
WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2007____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN concat(substring(url,1,41),'2007/',substring(url FROM 42))
WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2008____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN concat(substring(url,1,41),'2008/',substring(url FROM 42))
WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2009____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN concat(substring(url,1,41),'2009/',substring(url FROM 42))
WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2010____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN concat(substring(url,1,41),'2010/',substring(url FROM 42))
WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2011____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN concat(substring(url,1,41),'2010/',substring(url FROM 42))
WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2012____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN concat(substring(url,1,41),'2011/',substring(url FROM 42))
WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2013____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN concat(substring(url,1,41),'2012/',substring(url FROM 42))
WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2014____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN concat(substring(url,1,41),'2014/',substring(url FROM 42))
WHEN url LIKE 'http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/2015____-______-to-%.mp3' THEN concat(substring(url,1,41),'2015/',substring(url FROM 42))
/* do nothing */
ELSE url
END
```

Then it should work.  [Here's a SQL fiddle to show the difference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd2de7/1)

Comment: This is right. The CASE expression returns a *value*.  `CASE ... ELSE url = url END` does *not* perform an assignment. The expression `url = url` is evaluated as a value... the result of a comparison operation. If the comparison yields TRUE, MySQL returns a *value* of 1.  +10.

Answer (score 0):

If this is one-time work, you don't required to use SQL. You may dump the table:

```
mysqldump -u user -p database table > dump.sql
```

Make text replacements:

```
sed -i 's|\(http://abcdefgh.abcd.ca/podcasting/audio/\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([-to0-9]*\.mp3\)|\1\2/\2\3|g' dump.sql
```

And import the table back:

```
mysqlimport -u user -p database table < dump.sql
```

These commands are for Linux/Unix. If you're on Windows, you may do the same with your favorite tools.

Comment: Your sed command is wrong?

# sed -i 's|(podcasting/audio/)([0-9]{4})([to-0-9]*\.mp3)|$1$2/$2$3|g' dump.sql
sed: -e expression #1, char 59: Invalid range end

Comment: Nevermind, I had to change "podcasting/audio" to the full url

Comment: Yes, regexp lacked escaping, sorry. I wrote it just to demonstrate the concept and therefore not tested it on that moment. Now I've corrected it, you can use it if this method is suitable for you.